# Make sure no one steals your code

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if their is anyway you can prevent people from copy and pasting your code? Is their anyway i can access the URL of the page and compare it to the, for instance, website it belongs too. Like if i the url of the page does not equal, for instance, google.com, then it displays a error message. A example would be if i tried to copy and paste google searches code into my website, it would automatically detect the code isn't on google.com and give the error message like i said before. I am using codepen.io by the way.

Comment: If you put something on the Internet it's available to anybody who knows or discovers the URL.

Comment: Full form of URL is Uniform Resource Locator.

Comment: I dont want other people stealing my code. I dont care if its legal or not, i want to have something in the code that prevents copy and pasting.

Comment: Why so many dislikes?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make your code less readable by minifying/uglifying it. You could also disable right clicking on the site with the `preventDefault() method` but it's recommended to that. Another option I heard of would be to use JavaScript encryption but that would make your site usable only for browsers that have JavaScript enabled (most of them do, but it's considered a bad practice).

Comment: Okay, is their a easier method like comparing the users URL. Anyone stealing the code would just copy and paste it. `document.URL` might be a option. If the code is for google.com, then if the URL of the page is not "www.google.com" then you know they just copied and pasted the code. Users URL vs the page URL.